# How to use serverside processing in DT::datatable?

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I am using DT::datatable() to visualize tables in a R markdown file.

````
# R markdown file
library(DT)

```{r viewdata} 
# this is an example but my actual dataset has 10000 rows and 100 columns
var.df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1:10000), y = rnorm(1:10000),...)
DT::datatable(data = var.df)
```
````

When I run this code, I get a warning and the resulting HTML is very slow to load:

```
DT::datatable(var.df)
Warning message:
In instance$preRenderHook(instance) :
  It seems your data is too big for client-side DataTables. You may consider server-side processing: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html
```

I know that there is a `server = TRUE/FALSE` option in `DT::renderDataTable()`, but I don't see any server option in `DT::datatable`.

How do I use serverside processing using `DT::datatable()`?

Comment: there is actually no server with markdown: the HTML is generated once. Shiny has a server this is why you can render on server with `DT::renderDataTable()`

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Can you move your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Markdown has the option to be run as a shiny app [link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-start.html). Looking at the `datatable()` documentation any option from the underlying javascript library can be used, including `serverSide` [link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide). Yet this is not working.....

Comment: Ah, wrapping my call to `datatable()` inside `renderDataTable({})` was all that was required to make this work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning message says:

> It seems your data is too big for client-side DataTables. You may consider server-side processing: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html

On the documentation website, it shows a Shiny example, which uses `DT::renderDataTable()`. To use the server-side processing mode, you must have a "server" in the first place. `DT::datatable()` only produces a static HTML widget, and there is no server behind it. All data live in and is processed by your web browser.

Shiny is not the only possible server for **DT**, but probably the most convenient one (unless you really understand the technical details behind server-side processing). To use Shiny with R Markdown, see [Chapter 19 of the R Markdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-documents.html). Here is an example:

````
---
title: "The server-side processing mode for DT in R Markdown"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---


```{r}
DT::renderDT(ggplot2::diamonds)
```
````

Answer (score -1):

This function will start a shiny server and show the datatable.

Call it with an object returned by `DT::datatable`:

```
dtss <- function(dt) {
  ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
    shiny::titlePanel("Edgar Anderson's Iris Data"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$dt <- DT::renderDT({
      dt
    })
  }

  shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```