# Any 'large' data frame crashes R DataTable package - is there a solution?

Tags: r, datatables, dt

```
library(DT)
library(nycflights13)
datatable(flights)
#> Warning message:
#> In instance$preRenderHook(instance) :
#>   It seems your data is too big for client-side DataTables.
#>   You may consider server-side processing:
#>   https://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html
```

When I run the code above R Studio freezes, apparently hanging because the `nycflights13::flights` data frame is too large for the `DT` package.

[I found this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664434/how-to-use-serverside-processing-in-dtdatatable) that suggests wrapping everything in `renderDataTable({})` as a solution, but that doesn't seem to help anything. Am I even wrapping things properly?

```
renderDataTable({flights})
renderDataTable({datatable(flights)})
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a shiny (or other) server. Per [Yihui's answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664434/how-to-use-serverside-processing-in-dtdatatable).

````
---
title: "The server-side processing mode for DT in R Markdown"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(DT)
library(nycflights13)
renderDT(flights)
```
````

Comment: This is a RMarkdown document and per-se doesn't run any server at all

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to run for me:

```
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(nycflights13)
TEST<-as.data.frame(flights)
TEST<-setDT(TEST)
class(TEST)
```

Comment: I created a dataframe first, I didn't use    datatable(flights). It didn't crash for me.

Comment: thanks I just noticed that, but `datatable(TEST)` seems to have the same issue and froze R and R Studio for me. Tried on several machines. Can you try `datatable(flights)` maybe that'll your on your computer as well and the creation of `TEST` is unnecessary in your case.

Comment: It does give an error "It seems your data is too big for client-side DataTables...". Can you create a data.frame first?

Comment: I followed your routine above, followed by `datatable(TEST)` but R still freezes. I've tried on various machines Windows and Linux but it keeps freezing everything. Thanks for your attempt which appears to work in some circumstances.

Comment: This answer doesn't even visualize the dataframe with DT